# Delete Ubuntu files after Windows installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows, system-installation, delete

Yesterday, I installed Windows 64bit over Ubuntu because I had troubles with syncronising my devices. So today i will install Ubuntu as a Dualboot, I just want to make sure, that all Ubuntu files are deleted.

I just put in the windows CD in my Laptop, booted from it and deleted all partitions and insalled Windows. I also had to download after the installation a lot of updated and I installed Microsoft Office 2010. After that, I saw that already 29 Gig of my Harddrive are in use.

Is this normal? How can I make sure that all Linux files are deleted?

Many thanks for your help

Edhirdel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deleted all the partitions then Ubuntu is gone and also take note that Windows can't see Linux filesystems so you can't tell from Windows how much space is left on the Linux partition.

Windows take a lot of space, expecially recent versions such as windows 8. Office is another space consuming application. That said, 29GiB for just Windows and Office is a bit too much so maybe check if you have other software installed that are using your space.

Use Windows Disk cleanup and select C drive then select clean up system files too that may free up some space in your C drive

Comment: Does somebody know where i can check my used space?

Comment: if you want to know your used space you should go to C drive and check the size of the all the folder and files outside the folders listed in C drive and sum them up. you should un-hide all the hidden files and page files then you should check the size.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gparted live CD to make sure that you have deleted all previous sectors of your hard drive. This tool should allow you to remove linux completely. http://gparted.org/livecd.php
Hope it helps! Matt